# Sql match id's with names from a table that matches with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `friend` which has two columns with Id's that belong to specific usernames. See example:

[image: Friend table]

Id_Gebruiker is the user and Id_Gebruiker2 is the friend of the user.

The table `friend` has id's that belong to the table `user`.

Then that table `user` has Foreign Keys (column Id_Client) to the table `client` (referencing the Id_Client column). The `client` table contains the usernames.

Now I want to get the corresponding usernames that belongs to the Id's that the `Friend` table contains. So far I got it working when I use only two tables but I can't get it to work with three tables.

[image: User and client table]

Comment: It seems that `Id_Gebruiker` and `Id_Gebruiker2` are both related to column `Id` in `User table`? But, in answer you accepted you have  `Id_Gebruiker` related to `Id` of `Client table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select f.Id_Gebruiker, f.Id_Gebruiker2, u.Id_Client, c.Gebruikersnaam
from friend f 
join [user] u on f.Id_Gebruiker2 = u.Id
join client c on u.id_client = c.id
```

**EDIT** Assuming the names of the users are on the same table (`client`) and that every `friend.Id_Gebruiker` corresponds to a `client.Id` (so there exists a FK relationship), you can find both names with an extra join:

```
select c.Gebruikersnaam as UserName, c2.Gebruikersnaam as FriendName
from friend f
join client c on f.Id_Gebruiker = c.Id
join [user] u on f.Id_Gebruiker2 = u.Id
join client c2 on u.id_client = c2.id
```

Comment: Yeah it gives me the name of the friend, but I also need the name of the user. Like two rows to each other.

Comment: I see. In which table do you expect the name of the user? The `client` table as well?

Comment: Yes all the names comes from the Table client from the row Username.

Comment: Yes thank you ! I got it like this:  select f.Id_Gebruiker, f.Id_Gebruiker2, u.Id_Client, o.Gebruikersnaam as Gebruiker, c.Gebruikersnaam as Vriend 
from vriend f 
join gebruiker u on f.Id_Gebruiker2 = u.Id
join gebruiker y on f.Id_Gebruiker = y.Id
join client c on u.id_client = c.id
join client o on y.Id_Client = o.Id and it works now !

Comment: Great, take care!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer that you can check and verify at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b9dd/1.

The main query for getting names for userid and friendid in friends table is as below.

```
SELECT f1.userid, 
       f1.friendid, 
       y.username AS UserName, 
       x.username AS FriendName 
FROM   friends f1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT f.friendid, 
                                   c.clientname AS UserName 
                   FROM   users u 
                          INNER JOIN clients c 
                                  ON u.id_client = c.id 
                          INNER JOIN friends f 
                                  ON f.friendid = u.id) x 
               ON f1.friendid = x.friendid 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT f.userid, 
                                   c.clientname AS UserName 
                   FROM   users u 
                          INNER JOIN clients c 
                                  ON u.id_client = c.id 
                          INNER JOIN friends f 
                                  ON f.userid = u.id) y 
               ON f1.userid = y.userid;
```